# Изменения в compileSdkVersion и minSdkVersion

Tags: java, android

Такой вопрос, есть приложение, которое в релизе, там указано `compileSdkVersion` 23, и `minSdkVersion` 18, если я в следующей версии приложения укажу `compileSdkVersion` 25, и `minSDKversion`16 повлияет ли это на что-то? не повредит ли это проекту? Пропустит ли Google Play с измененными `compileSdkVersion` и `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: Поднятием `minSDKversion` Вы, как минимум, урезаете множество поддерживаемых устройств.

Comment: @post_zeew исправила вопрос, я наоборот хочу понизить minSDKversion.

Comment: значит вы просто расширите список поддерживаемых устройств

Comment: А повышение compileSdkVersion никак особо не повлияет на проект?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

minSDKversion - на каком минимальном API будет работать ваше приложение.

compileSDKversion - это "возможности" какого API используются при сборке проекта (классы какого API). Обычно ставится максимальное API. Так, если вы укажите этот параметр равным API 23, то возможности API 25 вам будут не доступны (ошибка сборки).

Повредить проекту уменьшение первого и повышение второго не может, так как вы расширяете список поддерживаемых устройств и API, а вот в обратную сторону может - при compileSDKversion 23, если раньше было 25 и вы использовали классы или методы, добавленные в этом API, то проект не соберется.

С Google Play проблем быть не может, иначе как бы реализовывалось обновление программ с поддержкой возможностей новых API