# Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio версия Android

Tags: visual-studio

В Android Studio при создании нового проекта нужно указать минимальную версию Android (Поддержка от минимальной до самой актуальной версии Android.

В Xamarin.Android таки параметров три:

```
Минимальная версия Android
Целевая версия Android
Скомпилировать с помощью версии Android (целевая платформа)
```

Может кто объяснить в чем между ними отличие? Ну вот минимальная это и так понятно, а что значит целевая версия? Целевая разве не должна быть - минимальной? По сути ведь есть обратная совместимость (почти).

И тот же вопрос по поводу "скомпилировать с помощью..."
Разве мы не должны там минимальную версию указывать, ведь именно эту версию мы хотим поддерживать, а старшие версии и так из-за обратной совместимости должны работать.

Comment: Это совершенно не относится к Xamarin  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion. Есть еще и ``maxSdkVersion``.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576459/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-compilesdkversion-%d0%b8-minsdkversion

Comment: Итак, это будет правильный порядок в соответствии с Android:
compiledSdkVersion = minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion.

Таким образом, это будет правильный порядок, согласно другим:
minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compiledSdkVersion (highest possible)
Даже в ответах у меня вызывает противоречие.
Допустим минимальную версию, которую я хочу поддерживать это 4.0.3. В настоящее время последняя версия 8.1, и что куда ставить?

Comment: Согласно первому это: min = compiled = 4.0.3 и targer -? И согласно второму: min 4.0.3, target -?, compiled - 8.1

Comment: @Эникейщик В этом и возникают для меня противоречия

Comment: Где написано, что compiledSdkVersion = minSdkVersion  <= targetSdkVersion? Наоборот везде указано, что для компиляции нужно использовать наивысшую версию СДК из доступных.

Comment: О, нашел. Оказывается, сам гугл [так и пишет](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element). В таком случае можно делать так, как хочется.

Comment: @Эникейщик хороший ответ =)

Comment: Да это не ответ :) Я, честно говоря, даже удивился, что мнение гугла расходится со мнением всех остальных (вернее наоборот - все остальные рекомендуют делать не так, как советует гугл). С практической точки зрения, мне кажется, лучше использовать для компиляции последнюю версию СДК, тогда не нужно хранить на диске гигабайты старых версий.

Comment: @Эникейщик Хорошо, а что в целевой версии устанавливать? тоже последнюю версию?

Comment: Это уже зависит. Вот [тут есть хорошие ответы с примерами](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version). И здесь [последний абзац](http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/mobile-apps/the-compile-sdk-minimum-sdk-and-target-sdk-versions/).

Answer (score 0):

## Целевая платформа(или compileSDKversion)

Например целевая платформа - API 29.

Это обозначает, что проект будет компилироваться, используя SDK 29-ой версии.

SDK - Software Development Kit (если я правильно понимаю, это библиотека классов, которыми мы пользуемся в приложении)

[image: Visual Studio printscreen]