# React native понижение SDK версии

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

Начал делать приложение на версии SDK 30, сейчас есть необходимость запустить на Android 7 (SDK 24). При изменении параметров в android/build.gradle c таких:

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
}
```

на такие

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "24.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 24
    targetSdkVersion = 24
    ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
}
```

получаю warning:

WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (24.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (29.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.1.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 29.0.2 will be used.

и ошибку

```
error: package java.nio.file does not exist
error: package java.nio.file.attribute does not exist

error: cannot find symbol
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
symbol:   variable O
  location: class VERSION_CODES
```

Что надо сделать для того, чтобы запустить приложение на версии SDK 24?

Comment: Запускайте себе пожалуйста, менять для этого ничего не надо. У вас и так `minSdkVersion = 21`, все будет работать на Андроид 5.0 и выше.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576472/184031